# What is the most pythonic way to extend a list with the reversal of another?

Tags: list, python, reverse

I have one list that I want to take a slice of, reverse that slice and append each of those items onto the end of another list.  The following are the options I have thought of (although if you have others please share), which of these is the most pythonic?

```
# Option 1
tmp = color[-bits:]
tmp.reverse()
my_list.extend(tmp)

# Option 2
my_list.extend(list(reversed(color[-bits:])))

# Option 3
my_list.extend((color[-bits:])[::-1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like

```
my_list.extend(reversed(color[-bits:]))
```

It explains what you are doing ( extending a list by reverse of another list's slice) and is short too.

and a obligatory itertools solution

```
my_list.extend( itertools.islice( reversed(color), 0, bits))
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking, it's almost self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list.extend(color[:-(bits + 1):-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For Option #2, you can cut out the call to `list`.  You could also use `+=` instead of `extend`, like so:

```
my_list += reversed(color[-bits:])
```